# How many "X"'s should I use to create temporary files safely and portably with `mktemp`?

Tags: shell, mktemp

From time to time, I create temporary files from shell scripts by invoking the command `mktemp` with 6 or more `X`'s in the argument `TEMPLATE`. However, I am unsure if that amount will work with other implementations of `mktemp` because I have found commands with different amounts (e.g., [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/1ffc120558bdfd528fc5740d6b6ea7c49f402639/Makefile#L252), [here](https://github.com/Asana/kubernetes/blob/486ec2b7c9f95a43a856d1d71077382bf6b23afa/cluster/common.sh#L512), and [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f5837722ffecbbedf1b1dbab072a063565f0dad1/tools/testing/selftests/net/big_tcp.sh#L7)).

I have researched a little bit and found the following:

- The GNU implementation of `mktemp` requires three or more `X`'s.
- The OpenBSD implementation of `mktemp` appears to require six `X`'s. However, I have little to no clue what the [underlying code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.bin/mktemp/mktemp.c#L80) does.
- The manuals for the FreeBSD implementation of the [`mktemp`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=1&n=1) command and [function](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+14.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) are rather vague with how many `X`'s the template should have.

Comment: FWIW, POSIX' [`mkstemp(3)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html#tag_16_326_07)

Comment: Why not just drop the template? For the user command It is optional.

Answer (score 1):

The portable option is six or more, because that's what `mkstemp(3)` does and that's the behaviour that's being emulated.  However, on some systems, specifying more than six results in only the trailing six being used and the remaining being left as `X`.  In any event, if a CSPRNG is being used internally, six should be sufficient to prevent an attacker from DoSing the process.

Note that on some systems (e.g., Linux with the GNU tools), you can drop the template altogether, although this is not portable.  Most systems require either a template or a prefix with `-t`, and if you want a file that is not in `$TMPDIR`, the template is required.  This is at least true of FreeBSD and macOS.

You may also find some systems which do not support `mktemp(1)` at all, since it is not required by POSIX.  However, it is widely available, and present on at least Linux, macOS, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, HP-UX, and Solaris, so you can probably simply tell people to install the GNU coreutils on any system lacking it.

Comment: Why would an attacker want to DoS a process?

Comment: Because they want to prevent it from running or performing a certain activity.  The reason that you can't just do `mkdir /tmp/myprog.$$` to create a temporary directory is because of the DoS possibility, since the attacker can just create one of those for every possible PID.